# Get Current Page Title and Id after post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get my current page id and title for reference but before I output them I override the global $post in my header.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $current_page_id = $post->ID;
    echo $current_page_id;
?>
```

This is my header code:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <?php
        $slides = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'slide' ) );
        foreach( $slides as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );
            $slide_url = get_slide_url();
            $slide_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "slide" );
            ?><a href="<?php echo $slide_url; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $slide_thumbnail[0]; ?>" /></a><?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
```

It returns the last used post but I want my current page post.

I have created a custom meta box for post type product to select a page to display on. I am trying to get posts of type product and of the current page id to output onto the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use '**wp_reset_query'** function before post id retrieving for this:

```
<?php 
wp_reset_query();
global $post;
$current_page_id = $post->ID;
 echo $current_page_id;
?>
```